# Beta regression in R (betareg) - parameter intepretation

Tags: r, regression

In a simple model, `x` is a continuous (normally distributed) variable predicting `y`. Since `y` values are proportions ranging from 0 to 1 (0%-100%), simple linear regression gives out-of-range estimates for some predicted values (i.e., lower than 1 or higher than 1). Therefore, I have decided to use beta regression (`betareg()` command in betareg R package). However, while it is easy to interpret the unstandardized regression parameter from a linear model (i.e., B = 0.126 indicating an increase by 12.6% of y if x rises by 1), I am not sure how to understand, transform, or use the parameters from `betareg` model.

Model: `betaMod = betareg(formula = y ~ x)`

Output:

```
Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)     
(Intercept) -4.85712    0.52580  -9.238   <2e-16 *** 
x            0.56796    0.06498   8.740   <2e-16 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)     
(phi)    7.686      1.184   6.491 8.54e-11 ***
```

How can I interpret the parameter `0.526` in the output (together with the intercept) to understand the increase in `y` (in %) when `x` increases by 1? In other words, knowing `x`, what can I say about unknown `y` if we assume the above model is useful?

Thank you!
M.

Comment: You might want to try this package (which explains the results of many analyses in plain English): https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/explainr/versions/0.1

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work with such class of R objects yet, I guess.

Comment: Have you read the package vignette?